# Calculate a matrix to the power of "n" given an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question that I simply cannot solve. I do not want a direct answer to the question but simply an explanation as to the steps one would take to go about solving it, that way I can try it myself. To avoid getting an answer to the problem I wish to solve, I will use variables in place of actual matrices.

Calculate $A^n$x where both **A** and **x** are known , and **x** is an eigenvector of **A**.

**A** is a 2-by-2 matrix.

For this question, I'm supposed to use the idea of linear combinations, which is what confuses me, I assume that means I'm supposed to solve it using the following format:

(This is my take on it, it is most likely wrong)

First find $\lambda$ -->  Ax = $\lambda$x

Then --> x = a $\lambda$x

Solve for **a** and then do something like --> $A^n$ = a$\lambda^n$x

I'm really unsure as to how to solve this, can someone point me in the right direction. Perhaps show me step by step what I need to do.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following what you wrote. It's not clear what **a** is. Can you try to calculate $A^2 x$?

Comment: @GitGud That's not necessary here. You're being misled by the title.

Comment: @user208259 I didn't read that $\mathrm x$ is an eigenvector, that's what I missed.

Comment: @user208259 sorry if its unclear, I don't think what I wrote matters too much, as it is definitely wrong, that was just my take on it. The important part is that I have to solve it using some kind of linear combination... if that makes sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$A\textbf{x}=\lambda \textbf{x}\Longrightarrow A^2\textbf{x}=AA\textbf{x}=A\lambda \textbf{x}=\lambda A\textbf{x}=\lambda\lambda \textbf{x}=\lambda^2 \textbf{x}$$
Conclude.

Answer (score 3):

If you know about diagonalizing a matrix and such, the formula $A=PDP^{-1}$ shouldn't be new to you. The cool thing about this is what happens when you take $A^2$:

\begin{align}
A&=PDP^{-1} \\
A^2&=(PDP^{-1})(PDP^{-1})
\end{align}

and because of associative law we can do $PP^{-1}$ first and that is equal to $I$. Reducing $A^2$ to $PDDP^{-1}$ which is $PD^2P^{-1}$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE, please consider using [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/570189) to improve readability.